# SQL Expected end of input but got keyword WHERE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am performing a SQL query using Python for a Big Query data set. I am getting an error and I could not figure out what do I need to fix on my own. This is the error log:

> Expected end of input but got keyword WHERE

The variable `vector_score` is a float (I also tried with an int and does the same thing)

Query:

```
sql = f"""
    SET lauder = lauder * %f 
    WHERE keyword= '%s'
    AND (date BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s')
    """ % (vector_score, keyword, starting_date, ending_date)
```

Parameters:

```
vector_score = 1.05
keyword = food
starting_date = '2020-01-10'
ending_date = '2020-01-17'
```

Comment: Have you try putting lauder_float * %f in brackets example: (lauder_float * %f)?

Comment: Also what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Are you missing the keyword `UPDATE` and a target table at the start of your statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the actual update command in your execution

```
UPDATE TARGET_NAME
SET lauder = lauder * %f 
    WHERE keyword= '%s'
    AND (date BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s')
```